# Metric pertubation in xAct

Tags: physics, tensors, differential-geometry, xact

I start to learn xAct. Following this thread:
[expanding-the-riemann-tensor-perturbation](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/104649/expanding-the-riemann-tensor-perturbation) I noticed that xAct set a default perturbation to the metric by:

```
DefManifold[M4, 4, IndexRange[a, f]]
DefMetric[{1, 3, 0}, g[-a, -b], CD]
DefMetricPerturbation[g, H, \[Epsilon]]
```

And then for instance the first order perturbation

```
Perturbed[g[-a, -b], 1]
```

gives:

```
g[-a, -b] + \[Epsilon]  h[-a, -b]
```

And what I understand that `g[-a, -b]` is a diagonal metric : `(-1,1,1,1)`.
What if I want to make another perturbation for a new metric: `met= a(t)^2 Exp[y] (-1,1,1,1)`

And the perturbation is given by:

$ g_{00}= a^2(t) ~ e^y ( 1+ 2 \phi^{(1)} + \phi^{(2)} )$

$ g_{0i}=0$

$g_{ij}= a^2(t)~ e^y [( 1- 2 \psi^{(1)}- \psi^{(2)})~\delta_{ij} +  \frac{1}{2} D_{ij} \chi_{ij}^{(2)}] $

Where:

$
 D_{ij} =\partial_i \partial_j - \frac{1}{3} \delta_{ij} \partial^k \partial_k  
$

Please also see this thread: [Simplifying the Einstein tensor in case of a perturbed FRW metric](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/posts/291367/edit)

Can this be fulfilled by xAct? or I need to use a another MA code? here the perturbation for each metric component $g_{00},g_{0i}$, and $g_{ij}$ is different. And the final expression I want to perturb is:

$
G_{\alpha\beta} = \frac{\nabla_\beta (\partial_\alpha \phi)}{\phi} - \frac{1}{2\phi^2} \left[ \frac{\partial_4 \phi \partial_4 g_{\alpha\beta}}{\phi} - \partial_4 (\partial_4 g_{\alpha\beta} ) + g^{\gamma\delta} \partial_4 g_{\alpha\gamma} \partial_4 g_{\beta\delta} - \frac{g^{\gamma\delta} \partial_4 g_{\gamma\delta} \partial_4 g_{\alpha \beta}}{2}+ \frac{g_{\alpha\beta}}{4}\left( \partial_4 g^{\gamma\delta} \partial_4 g_{\gamma\delta} + ( g^{\gamma\delta}
 \partial_4 g_{\gamma\delta})^2 \right)
 \right]
$

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: My apologies I did not think too much before writing this comment but is it possible to perturb with a general metric and then substitute the metric you want at the end?

Comment: also, my impression is that the xact google group https://groups.google.com/g/xact tends to be a bit more active than this website for xact questions

Comment: Finally, remember to use or consider using @ like @userrandrand in order to notify users that you replied in comments.